# Django FormWizard with different templates

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am trying to use `FormWizard` to make a registration for new users. Because in some steps I would need to use js,formsets, and photos, I decided to make a different template for each step. But then I got an error :

```
ValidationError at /registration_steps
[u'\u0414\u0430\u043d\u043d\u044b\u0435 ManagementForm \u043e\u0442\u0441\u0443\u0442\u0441\u0442\u0432\u0443\u044e\u0442 \u0438\u043b\u0438 \u0431\u044b\u043b\u0438 \u0438\u0441\u043a\u0430\u0436\u0435\u043d\u044b.']
```

**forms.py**

```
class ApplicantForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Password',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='confirm',
        widget=forms.PasswordInput
    )
    travel_passport = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=((False, 'Нет'), (True, 'Да')),
        widget=forms.Select
    )
    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords dont match')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(ApplCreaForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.isempl=0
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
    class Meta:
        model = ExtUser
        fields = ['email','firstname', 'lastname', 'middlename', 'date_of_birth', 'gender', 'family_position',
                  'driver_license', 'driver_license_category',]

class ApplicantForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExtUser
        fields = ['country','region','city', 'nearcity', 'travel_passport', 'travel_passport_end_date','metro', 'mobile_sms', 'mobile_double', 'email_double',
                  'web', 'vkontakte', 'facebook','odnoklasniki','skype','whatsapp','viber','ready_to_move','ready_to_move_where',]
```

**views.py**

```
FORMS_REG = [("reg_step1", ApplicantForm1),
         ("reg_step2", ApplicantForm2),
        # ("ApplicantForm3", ApplicantForm3),
        # ("ApplicantForm4", ApplicantForm4),
        # ("ApplicantForm5", ApplicantForm5),
        # ("ApplicantForm6", ApplicantForm6),
        # ("ApplicantForm7", ApplicantForm7),
        ]         

TEMPLATES_REG = {"reg_step1": "registration_steps/reg_step1.html",
             "reg_step2": "registration_steps/reg_step2.html",
             #"reg_step3": "registration_steps/reg_step3.html",
             #"reg_step4": "registration_steps/reg_step4.html",
             #"reg_step5": "registration_steps/reg_step5.html",
             #"reg_step6": "registration_steps/reg_step6.html",
             #"reg_step7": "registration_steps/reg_step7.html",
             }

class ApplicantWizard(SessionWizardView):
    instance = None
    def get_template_names(self):
        return [TEMPLATES_REG[self.steps.current]]
    def get_form_instance( self, step ):
        if self.instance is None:
            self.instance = ExtUser()
        return self.instance
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        self.instance.save()
        return render_to_response('app/successpage.html', {
            'title':"Registration complited" ,
        })
```

**urls.py**

```
 url(r'^registration_steps$', ApplicantWizard.as_view(FORMS_REG)),
```

templates **reg_step1.html** and **reg_step2.html** (for now they are same)

```
{% extends "layout/layout_main.html" %}

{% block content %}
<p> Step {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of  {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>
{% for field in form %}
    {{field.error}}
{% endfor %}

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
{{wizard.managment_form}}
    {{ wizard.form }}
</table>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">"first step"</button>
<button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">"prev step"</button>
{% endif %}

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Your error message says (in Russian) your management form is missing. Double-check whether both your templates contain the `{{wizard.managment_form}}` line.

Comment: Yes, both templates contain that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As form wizard complains about the missing management form, the problem seems to be related to nested formsets. Make your relevant template section look like:

```
<table>
    {{ wizard.management_form }}
    {% if wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
        {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {{ wizard.form }}
    {% endif %}
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it helps. But now I got another problem. I need to set password for user. Iam using somthing like   def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        user=ExtUser()
        user = self.instance.save()
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.save() but got an error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Comment: `Model.save()` doesn't return an instance of self. You should go with something like `self.instance.set_password(...)`.

Comment: past_data =  self.get_all_cleaned_data()
        self.instance.set_password(past_data(['password1']))
        self.instance.save got 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Rather hard to say, your particular lines don't seem to be ones which cause the exact error message. I think the best solution is to ask another question, posting relevant code.